# "cannot import name Polygon" in geodjango

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, geodjango

I am trying to follow [this simple tutorial](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/geodjango-maps-with-leaflet.html) to show markers on my leaflet meap on my webpage. However, I get the following error:

> from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import Polygon ImportError:
>   cannot import name Polygon

as a result of this statement `from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView` in my `urls.py`

I'm not sure how to solve this, I have installed all the required dependencies for geodjango and can't find a package called 'Polygon'..

Here's the full error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fbe7c083050>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/src/newsparser/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('textnews.urls')),
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/src/textnews/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
  File "/home/mohamed/Dropbox/newsparse/newsparser/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djgeojson/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import Polygon
ImportError: cannot import name Polygon
```

Comment: Can you check that GEOS (as part of GeoDjango) was installed properly?

Comment: yep, pretty sure it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import seems broken with Django 1.9 https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson/issues/68